# 3D BPP algorithm in Python

Tags: python, bin-packing

I'm working on an algorithm to optimize the packing of items in boxes.

I can have up to 20 items which I need to pack in as few boxes as possible (6 possible box sizes), while minimizing the wasted volume within the boxes. I thought of implementing a variation of the **3D BPP algorithm** - which solves part of my problem - but cannot find any algorithm **written in Python**.

Does anyone have suggestions of the way to go or of python algorithms for 3D BPP which I could use?

Thanks!

Comment: This is quite broad...mind specifying an example so we know what exact data is your input and desired output?

Comment: Yes: I have the list of items which customers have ordered over the past year (for each item: height, width, length) on the one hand and a list of 6 boxes. First step: I am trying to see for each order what boxes to choose to pack the items (I want to have all of them in 1 box as much as possible) and second step: revamp the boxes' sizes to optimize the packing considering the past orders.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the problem you want to solve here is NP-complete, so there are no great absolute solutions to this problem, but the following papers provide some nice heuristic algorithms which are not difficult to implement.

[OPTIMIZING THREE-DIMENSIONAL BIN PACKING THROUGH SIMULATION](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bb99/86af2f26f7726fcef1bc684eac8239c9b853.pdf?_ga=1.50320358.1394974689.1485463187)

[Three-dimensional packings with rotations](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~fkm/publication/rotation.pdf)

[An Improved Three-Weight Message-Passing Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1961.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The first link posted by Don Thousand, "Optimizing...", has not lasted three years.  Another 3D packer, Enzo Ruiz, has saved it on his GitHub page
https://github.com/enzoruiz/3dbinpacking
the link to the paper by Erick Dube is https://github.com/enzoruiz/3dbinpacking/blob/master/erick_dube_507-034.pdf